# Why does sizeof(D) equal 2 in this code (see details)?

Tags: c++

```
struct X {};
struct D : X {
    X x;
};
```

According to http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#sizeof-empty, empty base class adds zero to the size.