# Can the compiler exploit empty base optimisation if the class contains a member of the base class?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider

```
struct base {};
struct child : base {};
```

It's well-known that `sizeof(child)` can be 1 by application of the *empty base optimisation*.

Now however, consider

```
struct base {};
struct child : base {base b;};
```

Can the compiler apply the empty base optimisation now, or must `sizeof(child)` be at least 2?

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo

Comment: As this is an optimization, what compiler and optimization flags did you use?

Comment: But you also have a member that is of type `X`, and you cant have zero-sized members. So clearly `sizeof(X)` is 1, not 0, and there are two instances of `X`, thus `sizeof(D)` is 2.

Comment: Here http://ideone.com/DSLOrY. The behavior is different for non-X base empty class.

Comment: It is not. Please go by the link.

Comment: Upvoted. Judging by the reception of my answer, this is deeper than I thought.

Comment: @RaymondChen this question was asked earlier.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44908996/why-does-sizeofd-equal-2-in-this-code-see-details

Comment: No it isn't. The focus is entirely different. Let's spend our "mod time" spotting obvious duplicates.

Comment: It is exactly the same question, slightly different wording. But feel free to disagree.

Comment: @Bathsheba How should the fact that you'll hit anyway the rep cap influence the fact that it's a dup or not? Not all of us are here on SO to hit a rep cap on a daily basis. This is a good question, as usually are your questions. Probably a dup, I agree, but I didn't get your last comment. I'm sorry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does sizeof(D) equal 2 in this code (see details)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44908996/why-does-sizeofd-equal-2-in-this-code-see-details)

Comment: The linked nature of these pair of questions probably needs a moderator to sort out. I've flagged.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, it cannot. From the same reference:

> Empty base optimization is prohibited if one of the empty base classes
>   is also the type or the base of the type of the first non-static data
>   member

Thus `sizeof(child) >= 2`.

Comment: IMO, questions tagged [language-lawyer] should be answered with quotes from the actual spec, by its very definition. While cppreference is quite good, it is not the actual definition of how C++ works, and it has need wrong in the past.

Comment: @Baum mit Augen thanks for pointing that out, I'm a bit new around here. It's fair to say that the other answers provided here are better than mine, then. I'll go through the relevant sections of the standard and I'll update my answer if I find something worth adding.

Answer (score 16):

The rule is that sub-objects of the same type cannot be at the same address. You have 2 `X` sub-objects here, hence each one must be at a different address.

Objects of the same type cannot share the same address because the identity of an object in C++ is its address. If multiples objects of the same type share the same address they are indistinguishable. And this is why the minimum complete object size is 1, so that each object in an array has a distinct address. See "§ The C++ object model [intro.object]":

> An object is a region of storage.
>
> ...
>
> Objects can contain other objects, called subobjects. A subobject can be a member subobject (9.2), a base class subobject (Clause 10), or an array element. An object that is not a subobject of any other object is
>   called a complete object.
>
> ...
>
> Unless it is a bit-field (9.6), a most derived object shall have a non-zero size and shall occupy one or more bytes of storage. Base class subobjects may have zero size.
>
> ...
>
> Unless an object is a bit-field or a base class subobject of zero size, the address of that object is the address of the first byte it occupies. Two objects that are not bit-fields may have the same address if one is a subobject of the other, or if at least one is a base class subobject of zero size and they are of different types; otherwise, they shall have distinct addresses.

This is why, for example, `boost::noncopyable` can increase a class size if one inherits it more than once unwittingly indirectly through empty base classes. E.g. in:

```
struct A : boost::noncopyable {};
struct B : boost::noncopyable {};
struct C : boost::noncopyable {};
struct D : A, B, C {};
```

`sizeof(D) == 3` because there are three distinct `boost::noncopyable` sub-subjects. If derivation from `boost::noncopyable` is dropped, then `sizeof(D) == 1`.

Comment: I don't understand, why can't subobjects share the same address? They're empty and thus stateless, what happens when they share the same address?

Comment: @PasserBy Sub-objects of the same type cannot share the same address because the identity of an object in C++ is its address. If multiples objects of the same type share the same address they are indistinguishable.

Comment: If the size of an object could be 0 then `X x[10]; for (X *p = x[0]; p < &x[10]; ++p) {...}` would make 0 loops for example.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Your example is different. It is about why minimum complete object size is 1.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow That is a statement that an object must not have zero size, not that some objects can't overlap

Comment: Why does stateless objects need identity? I seriously don't see a reason for that

Comment: Ok, not the best example. The point I was trying to make is that the address of subobjects of the same type must be unique so that comparisons (`p < &x[10`) don't give false positives.

Comment: @PasserBy How else would you distinguish the stateless objects then?

Comment: @PasserBy Because you can take their address and use that e.g. as key in a hashtable.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow But it is already illegal to compare pointers not from the same array, having the base and the member overlap here should in theory not affect what you said

Comment: @Maxim: could you add a quote from the Standard?

Comment: But since they are stateless, you have no reason to store them anywhere

Comment: @PasserBy That is not correct. It's legal to compare with equality any pointer with any other pointer of the same type.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I meant compare as in `<` or `>`, I thought its illegal isn't it?

Comment: @PasserBy It's illegal to advance a pointers outside of its allocations (comparison I think is legal and verry common) but in your class D both the inherited X and the member X are in the same allocation anyway.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Oh, that's news to me. But the point remains, of what use does stateless objects having identity afford?

Comment: What use you make of it is up to you. The standard is just written so that if you use them they don't blow up.

Comment: I've just tested MSVC++2015 and Intel Parallel Studio. Both compilers treat that `sizeof X` is equal to `sizeof D` and both equal to 1. Moreover, address of object of `D` is equal to the address of member `D::x`. Is it compiler bug?

Comment: @SergeGoncharov If identity (addresses) of `X` subobjects is not examined, the compiler may optimize. Compare `&d.x == &static_cast<X&>(d)`.

Comment: @Maxim: `if (&d==&d.x)  puts("Bwuahaha!");` - should this give message? It gives on both compilers.

Comment: @SergeGoncharov `printf("%d\n", &d == &d.x);` outputs 0 with clang++ and g++.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Yes, I know that both Clang and GCC work as you say. The thing is that MS/Intel compilers think different.

Comment: @SergeGoncharov MS C++ compilers conformance have not historically been exemplary.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I can understand what you wrote in the [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44909407/can-the-compiler-exploit-empty-base-optimisation-if-the-class-contains-a-member/44909645#comment76795251_44909130) but AFAICU that still doesn't answer the OP's question. Suppose, a compiler (fictitious) gives the same address to the two subobjects `base` in the question. What could go wrong with the resulting code?

Answer (score 14):

Objects in C++ are required to have unique "identity". From [intro.object]/8 (N4659):

> Two objects `a` and `b` with overlapping lifetimes that are not bit-fields may have the same address if one is nested within the other, or if at least one is a base class subobject of zero size and they are of different types; otherwise, they have distinct addresses.

A base class subobject and a member subobject are separate objects; neither is "nested within" the other. Therefore, if they are of the same type, they must have separate addresses.

Note that this extends *recursively*. Consider the following:

```
struct eb1 {};

struct eb2 : eb1 {};
struct not_empty(eb1 a;};

struct derived : eb2 {not_empty b;};
```

Because of the unique identity rule of C++, `derived::eb2::eb1` *must* have a different address from `derived::b::a`. Therefore, the compiler *cannot* employ EBO on `derived`.

Comment: A question going a bit deeper along that way: [Can the compiler optimize out the empty base if the class contains a member of base class type as first element, followed by other members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44914678/can-the-compiler-optimize-out-the-empty-base-if-the-class-contains-a-member-of-b)

Answer (score 6):

I'll plop in another more basic quote

[[intro.object]](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#8)

> Two objects a and b with overlapping lifetimes that are not bit-fields may have the same address if one is nested within the other, or if at least one is a base class subobject of zero size and they are of different types; otherwise, they have distinct addresses.

---

Since `b` is not an subobject of the inherited `base`, they must have distinct addresses.

Comment: As am I. Let's reverse it. (Although now really your question comment is obsolete.)

Comment: @Bathsheba Yeah, but that was before I found the exact quote in the standard :P